# Change JCheckBox 'ticked' color

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcheckbox, uimanager

How do I change or modify the color of the `JCheckBox` symbol (not the text property). I'm testing `UIManager.put("CheckBox.selected", Color.RED)` without success.

Can someone help?

Comment: Try `"CheckBox.select"`, although it is ignored by some UI delegates.

Comment: `JCheckBox` uses a `icon` for both the selected and unselected icons (both must be set), so the only way to change there color would be to change the icon

Answer (score 4):

`JCheckBox` uses the `icon` and `selectedIcon` to represent the "selected" and "unselected" states.

The only way you can change those is to use your own icon. For example...

[image: CustomCheckBox]

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {
    
    public TestPane() {
        try {
            JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox();
            cb.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(...)));
            cb.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(...)));
            cb.setBackground(Color.RED);
            cb.setOpaque(true);
            add(cb);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

If you just want to change the background color of `JCheckBox` instead, you'll need to make it opaque first:

```
cb.setBackground(Color.RED);
cb.setOpaque(true);
```

because they are transparent by default.

Comment: Thank you - Opaque was what I needed.  I'll also report for the other seekers there is no margin, etc on check-box labels.  So some more finesse is required than just a colour change.  _Nice_

Answer (score 0):

```
  UIManager.put("CheckBox.focus",Color.RED); //on focus
  UIManager.put("CheckBox.select",Color.RED) //on select

  checkBox1.setForeground(Color.RED); //you can call this in the combobox action listner
  checkbox1.setBackground(Color.Blue); //changing the background color
```

can u check with this code.

Comment: Same behavior. I'm running Java 8.60 on Win7.

Comment: made some changes to the answer you can try now

Answer (score 0):

for change checkbox inside color you can use this in main

```
try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to set LookAndFeel");
    }
```

[check box and radio button inside color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx3MK.jpg)